# Problem running Hive shell commands over ssh

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, hive, beeline

I need to send shell commands over ssh within a Hive script during its execution. The main goal is to be able to stress test an Apache Ozone cluster with various shell commands like stress-ng, netem, etc.

Note: The ssh user has no passphrase, it is just a test environment.

From the CLI, this simple command is working:

```
!sudo -u user ssh user@host 'ls'
```

But this one isn't working:

```
!sudo -u user ssh user@host 'ls -al'
```

Result: bash: ls -al: command not found Command failed with exit code = 127

The command '!ls -al' will work on the server itself, but no with ssh.

I got the same results with beeline.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Drop the quotes.

Comment: why are you using `!sudo` instead of only sudo ?

Comment: Dropping the quotes was the right answer! Thank you @Armali!

Comment: I rolled back your last edit because the answer doesn't belong in the question. On this site, [we maintain a strict separation between questions and answers](/tour). If you've found the solution to your own problem, that's great! Please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) in the space for an answer below.